# Autorun jar on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) after boot up, rc.local not working?

Tags: jar, raspberry-pi, autorun, raspbian

I want to auto run a .jar file after my Raspberry Pi boots up.

Normally I execute to .jar file with the following command (works great):

```
sudo java -classpath .:phidget21.jar -jar TestSensor.jar
```

(I can't simply use java -jar TestSensor.jar since the phidget21.jar needs to be appended to make the TestSensor.jar work properly)

Now, I want to execute the above command at the boot up of my raspberry pi.

As suggested in many places I tried to solve it with the rc.local file.

I added the following two lines:

```
cd /home/pi
sudo java -classpath .:phidget21.jar -jar TestSensor.jar
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Even

```
cd /home/pi
sudo java -jar TestSensor.jar
```

Doesn't start the TestSensor.jar on a boot up.

What am I doing wrong? Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that with `crontab`. As `root` using eg. `crontab -e` (the recommended way of editing the `crontab` file) you can add the line

```
@reboot /usr/bin/java -classpath /home/pi/:/home/pi/lib/phidget21.jar -jar /home/pi/TestSensor.jar
```

As indicated you may have to add full paths to `java`, elements in the classpath and `TestSensor.jar`. You should replace "my" paths with the actual locations of your `java` and JARs.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :D Unfortunately just adding @reboot -classpath .:phidget21.jar -jar TestSensor.jar at the end of the crontab file doesn't work.
I'm quite new to linux and I'm not quite sure what you mean with "You may have to add full paths to java, elements in the classpath and TestSensor.jar" If the phidget21.jar and the TestSensor.jar are both located at /home/pi/ how should the command look like?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the actual `java` executable previously. I also added (example) paths and a little more explanation. In general, you should be able to run everything after `@reboot` from a normal (root) command line. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but there still seems to be a problem. When I type into the terminal: sudo /usr/bin/java -classpath /home/pi/:/home/pi/lib/phidget21.jar -jar /home/pi/TestSensor.jar the .jar file gets execute and works perfectly. But it doesn't get execute if I put that line into the crontab file. Note: the jar file also open an form(interface). I'm not sure if that has something to do with it??

Comment: Are you running GNOME/KDE on Raspbian or do you mean a `tty`? In any  case, `cron` won't have an X `DISPLAY` or the same `tty` as your login shell so it won't work. You'll have to use the facilities in GNOME/KDE to auto start or start it in  `~pi/.bash_profile`...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I'm running Raspbian (optimized Debian) on my Raspberry Pi and everything works fine if I use the above command in the terminal when raspbian started up. Then, the window from the jar file opens on the desktop and I see what I should see. But no window opens if I just boot the raspberry pi. I'm sorry if I've misunderstand your question, but I'm kind of new to all this.

Comment: OK, read this article - it should work with MATE Desktop as well: http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/08/add-an-application-to-gnomes-autostart/

Comment: There is no such Menu in Raspbian. Would have been to easy.  I am not neither MATE nor GNOME. Raspian doesn't provide such an interface/feature.
I just realized that I actually asked my question the wrong way. It should say "after login" not "after boot".

Comment: Have a [look here](http://www.fam.tuwien.ac.at/~schamane/_/blog:110814_bash_shell_startup_files_in_debian_squeeze). I sugggest you add your java commandline to `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile` if you prefer) - that should work.